# Delete multiple Columns with simple macro

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to take TSPI flight data and strip out roughly 30-40 columns, each log contains roughly 3600 rows per hour. Once it has been stripped I need to reorganize the left over columns. I would like to do this the easiest fastest way, if there is one. I am not sure how to post an example of the excel data on these forums.

I have tried this code but I get runtime error 9

Sub sbVBS_To_Delete_Specific_Multiple_Columns()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B,H:L,P:Q,S:BJ").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

Nm I have figured it out the sheet was named 12-20-2016 so had to change the sheet1 to 12-20-2016.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. You can use [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/) to format your example to post here. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: It isn't clear from the last sentence you added whether that refers just to the error message in your formula but you still have a task you need help with, or that solved your problem and you no longer need help from people here.  Can you clarify?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Sort

It is possible to sort columns, not just rows, of data. Assuming you have some kind of header in row 1 that can be used as a sort key, you can do the following:

1 Hit Ctrl+End to go to the last used row and column

2 Hit Shift+Ctrl+Home to select everything between the first cell and the last used cell

3 Go to Data | Sort to open the Sorting interface

4 Click Options at the top of the Sorting interface

5 Under Orientation, select Sort Left to Right and click OK

You will now have the option of which row to sort by. Select a row that contains some value you want to sort by, then click OK. Blank columns will be sorted to the end and can then be ignored.

### Delete as you go

This is more for future reference, but it may be better to select entire columns and delete them rather than deleting just their contents. To do this:

1 Click on the column header letter at the very top to select the entire column

2 Either right-click on the column header letter and choose Delete, or go to the Home tab | Cells group | Delete | Delete sheet columns

Edited to Add:

### Macro it

As was pointed out, you did request a macro in the question title. While the methods I described could be automated with a recorded macro, here's a quick written one that will remove any completely empty column from the used range.

```
Sub ClearEmpties()
    'Delete any entirely empty column in the workshee's used range

    Dim l As Long

    For l = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(l)) = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(l).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next l

End Sub
```

This loops through every column in the used range, checks whether there are any non-blank cells in the column, and if there are none it deletes the entire column. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is certainly a good way to do it. But considering the title, "*Delete multiple Columns with simple macro*", I believe the OP was looking for something more automated.

Comment: Good point, I missed that in the OP's title - without the Excel VBA tag I was looking for a non-macro solution. I'll edit to add.